# Pantheon-files create a folder or file on network share (bug)

Tags: pantheon-files, folder, samba

(Sorry for my english, i am french)

Hello,

When creating a new folder or a new file in a Samba network share or WebDAV, the folder or file is created with the name "new folder" (nouveau dossier in french) or "new file" (nouveau fichier in french) but it's not him it's possible rename, this is the first record (alphabetical order) either for a new folder or a new file.

The new folder or file retains the name "new folder" or "new file" when the wrong folder is renamed with the new name instead of the new folder or file.

This problem is random. Sometimes it does, sometimes not.

What to do ? Thank you.

[image: create a folder or file on network share]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which is currently being worked on - see:
lp:~jeremywootten/pantheon-files/various-fixes-part3-fix-network-file-operations.

In the meantime, you could try creating and renaming the file locally and then uploading it.

Comment: Ok, thanks ;-) At least the bug is known, it's good.